# How to add smooth transitions to mouse X and Y coordinates with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a function that let a DOM element follow the mouse cursor.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXdxZO?editors=0110

When you hover over each item, the pointer will follow your mouse movements. Now I'm searching for some nice animation that can be added to this code. I was thinking about a little delay with ease transition. I already tried to use `transition: all 0.1s ease;` but this works a little buggy and not "smooth" enough. I know there is also something called `cubic`, but I don't know if that's what I needed.

I think there should be a function that will ease the mouse X and Y coordinates with a little smooth delay added to it.

**The part that delegate the mouse movement is:**

```
function mouseMove(event) {
  var target = $(this);
  var dot = target.find('.pointer');

  var height = dot.height();
  var width = dot.width();

  var offset = target.offset();
  var w = target.width();
  var h = target.height();
  var top = offset.top;
  var left = offset.left;
  console.log(left);

  var mX = (event.clientX - left) - width / 2 - 15; // 15 = padding
  var mY = (event.clientY - top) - height / 2;
    
  $(dot).css('-webkit-transform', 'translate3d(' + mX + 'px , ' + mY + 'px, 0) scale(1, 1)');

};
```

**Pointer CSS:**

```
.pointer {  
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
      transform: translateZ(0) scale(0);
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(0);
}

.pointer:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

I am seeking advice, resources, or maybe code parts that I should need.

Another thing that I want to animate smoothly is the `scale` property of the `pointer` class. When the mouse is enter the thumbnail it should scale to 1, if leaves the area, it should scale back to zero.

Comment: maybe this fiddle can help? http://jsfiddle.net/88526/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is all I did:-)

```
*{  -webkit-transition:1s;
transition:1s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,0.58,1);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,0.58,1);}
```

Cheers